# How does unlink() find the file to delete?

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony1, thumbnails

My app has a '`Photo`' field to store URL. It uses `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` for the widget schema. To delete the old image when a new image is uploaded, I use unlink before setting the value in the over-ridden setter and it works!!!

```
if (file_exists($this->_get('photo')))
    unlink($this->_get('photo'));
```

1. Photos are stored in uploads/photos and when saving '`Photo`' only the file name `xxx-yyy.zzz` is saved (and not the full path). However, I wish to know how symfony/php knows the full path of the file to be deleted?

Part 2:
I am using `sfThumbnailPlugin` to generate thumbnails. So the actual code looks like this:

```
public function setPhoto($value)
    {   
        if(!empty($value))
            {
                Contact::generateThumbnail($value); // delete current Photo & create thumbnail
                $this->_set('photo',$value);    // setting new value after deleting old one
            }
    }   

    public function generateThumbnail($value)
    {
                $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('app_photo_upload'); // path to upload folder
                if (file_exists($this->_get('photo')))
                {
                  unlink($this->_get('photo')); // delete full-size image
                  // path to thumbnail
                  $thumbpath = $uploadDir.'/thumbnails/'.$this->get('photo'); 
                  // read a blog, tried setting dir manually, doesn't work :(
                  //chdir('/thumbnails/');
                  // tried closing the file too, doesn't work! :(
                  //fclose($thumbpath) or die("can't close file"); 
                  //unlink($this->_get('photo'));   // doesn't work; no error :( 
                  unlink($thumbpath);   // doesn't work, no error :(
                }

                 $thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(150, 150);
                 $thumbnail->loadFile($uploadDir.'/'.$value);
                 $thumbnail->save($uploadDir.'/thumbnails/'.$value, 'image/png');
    }
```

2. Why can't the thumbnail be deleted using unlink()? is the sequence of ops incorrect?
   Is it because the old thumbnail is displayed in the `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` widget?

I've spent hours trying to figure this out, but unable to nail down the real cause.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question, but have you checked filesystem permissions?  Are you sure the account your PHP script is running under has permissions to actually delete the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved & Surprised

OK, here is the code that worked after adding some echoes...

```
public function generateThumbnail($value)
    {
             $uploadDir = sfConfig::get('app_photo_upload'); // path to upload folder
                // path to thumbnail
             $thumbpath = $uploadDir.'/thumbnails/'.$this->get('photo'); 
             if (file_exists($uploadDir.$this->_get('photo')))
             {
            >>    unlink($uploadDir.$this->_get('photo')); // delete full-size image
            >>    unlink($thumbpath); // delete thumn
             }

    //thumbnail generation code
    }
```

Supposedly, the `unlink($this->_get('photo'))` never worked. Infact, the if(fileExists) block was never entered and yet the file was deleted.
I think `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` was deleting the full-image automatically when a new one was being uploaded.

Thanks Martin & Kanak

Answer (score 2):

$path = "uploads/photos";
    $image = "Name of image";

```
unlink($path.$image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this line?

```
$thumbpath = $uploadDir.'/thumbnails/'.$this->get('photo');
```

I think you should use `$this->_get('photo');` instead of `$this->get('photo');`

Maybe try to dump `$thumbpath` variable.

```
var_dump($thumbpath); exit;
```